# Avoid triggering 'Select' triggers when using Excel Find functionality

Tags: excel, vba, find

I have a verry complicated excel template to administrate, that has a large number of trigggers: `Workbook_SheetDeactivate, Workbook_SheetActivate, Workbook_SheetSelectionChange, workbook_SheetChange`

If the users use Find functionality and choose within Workbook - Find next, this will trigger allot of them, and will most likely freeze the file because of so many commands.

Is there any way to controll the triggers in case of using Find?

Comment: .enableevents or use a public boolean flag to say to bypass code if true/false

Comment: i am aware, but how do i trigger it before the Find event? We are talking about non-technical users, so i need to do something to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 1):

When a user tries to find something (either by `Ctrl + F` or clicking the "Find" button) the `Cells.Find` sub is run.  The question then becomes, "Is it possible to run VBA code before executing user input?".  I don't think that's possible.

If you could guarantee that your users would only search via pressing `Ctrl + F` then you could make use of `Application.OnKey`.  Effectively, you would rewrite the `Cells.Find` sub, but wrap it in `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = True`.  That way, whenever your users pressed `Ctrl + F`, events would be disabled, the search would occur, and then events would enable again.

Answer (score 1):

If there really is a danger of your file freezing then the first thing you need to consider is your code: you have coded all of your events at the *Workbook* level, rather than at the *Worksheet* level - this facilitates writing *less* code, but it does mean that the code is run **more** often....

You can't guarantee that a non-technical user will not use CTRL+F (or your local equivalent) but if your file really does freeze if they use another method then they *will* learn not to repeat their mistake (given that CTRL+F is standard across many Windows applications, it is reasonable to assume that it will be the standard method chosen by users).

In the `Workbook_Open()` event of your workbook you can use the [OnKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey) method to trap the CTRL+F (or your local equivalent) key combination to run a procedure which includes the lines below

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.CommandBars("Edit").Controls("Find...").Execute
```

The problem then is that your events are disabled, as there isn't a way to detect when the user has finished using the *Find* window - I think you have 3 choices

- use the [OnTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime) method to call a procedure to re-enable events after a fixed interval
- use [DoEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function) in a loop (effectively allowing the user to maintain some use of the user interface) until some specific action has occurred, e.g `ActiveCell.Address` is a defined value
- create a dedicated button somewhere (e.g. a non-modal UserForm) so that the user can click it to re-enable events